# android google mapview

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview

The Google Map in android application shows blank grids??? I use Google Maps Api v2 and I get my Android Api key, put it in activity_main.xml as in tutorials, also get Internet permission in manifest file, use library of google.android.aps. I don't know how to solve it?

Comment: Are there any error messages in the logcat?

Comment: did u generate your own generate API key or used the one from tutorial?

Comment: We need a little more information :)